# When is the support of a Radon measure separable?

Tags: pr.probability, gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space, equipped with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(X)$, and let $\mathbb P$ be a Radon probability measure on $(X, \mathcal B(X))$. Recall that the support of the measure $\mathbb P$ is the smallest closed set of full measure.

Is the support necessarily separable? If so, why? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: What about Haar measure on a compact, non-separable group?
(By the way, don't you mean "smallest closed set with full measure"?).

Comment: Good, concise answer, and thanks for the pointer on the typo. Thanks, @jbc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I$ be a set of cardinality larger than the continuum. Then the product topology $[0,1]^{I}$ is compact but not separable. Give the interval $[0,1]$ the Lebesgue measure, then give $[0,1]^{I}$ the product measure $\mu$. If $U$ is a non-empty open subset of $[0,1]^{I}$, then $U$ contains a basic open set $\prod_{i\in I}U_{i}$ where $|\{i\in I|U_{i}\neq[0,1]\}|$ is finite. Therefore $0<\mu(\prod_{i\in I}U_{i})\leq \mu(U)$. Said differently, if $C$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]^{I}$ with $\mu(C)=1$, then $C=[0,1]^{I}$.

If you replace $[0,1]$ with the circle $S$, then $S^{I}$ is a compact non-separable group which does not have separable support as jbc mentioned.

Comment: A priori, $\mu$ is only defined on the product $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]^I$, which is strictly smaller than the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  How do we extend $\mu$ to a Borel measure?  And once this is done, how do we see that the measure is Radon?

Comment: It appears that this follows from Theorems 7.14.3 and 7.2.2 (iii) of Bogachev's *Measure Theory*.  It would be nice if there were a simpler example.

Comment: Bogachev has other notes and references in Section 7.14 (viii).

Comment: The reason I suggested using a group was to avoid such questions, since in this situation you can  use the existence theorem for Haar measure (which, by the way, has a very short and transparent proof in the case of a compact group, using the weak star compactness of the dual ball of $C(K)$).  A particularly simple solution to the OP is then provided by
a large cardinal product of the two-point group.

Comment: The product $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]^{I}$ contains every Baire set, so since $[0,1]^{I}$ is compact we can extend this Baire measure to a Radon measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in a unique way.